# Lists pass by value?

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to make a copy of my list that contains arraylists inside of it, but when I edit the copied value, the original values gets changed, which means am passing my ref, I tried all sorts of methods like using the copy method for each item, or creating a list/mutable list from the original but it didn't work, so my question is how do you pass a value in kotlin instead of ref?

I made the original as val and its field too.

```
class FAQAdapter(val faqModel: MutableList<FAQSection>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<FAQAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    val faqOriginal: List<FAQSection>
    var faqSectionsCopy: MutableList<FAQSection>

    init {
        faqOriginal = faqModel
        faqSectionsCopy = faqModel.toMutableList()
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        return ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.faq_section_item, parent, false))
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return faqSectionsCopy.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {

        holder.faqSectionHeading.text =
                faqSectionsCopy.get(holder.adapterPosition).sectionheader

        holder.questionsRecyclerView.layoutManager =
                LinearLayoutManager(holder.itemView.context,
                        LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false)

        holder.questionsRecyclerView.adapter =
                FAQQuestionsAdapter(faqSectionsCopy.get(holder.adapterPosition)
                        .faqQuestions)

        holder.questionsRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)

        holder.questionsRecyclerView.minimumHeight = convertDpToPx(holder.itemView.context, 88) * faqSectionsCopy.get(holder.adapterPosition).faqQuestions.size

    }

    fun filter(text: String) {
        var text = text.trim().toLowerCase()
//        faqSectionsCopy.clear()

        if (text.isEmpty()) {
//            faqSectionsCopy = faqModel as ArrayList<FAQSection>
        } else {
            text = text.toLowerCase()

            faqSectionsCopy.map {
                faqSectionsCopy[0].faqQuestions = it.faqQuestions.filter { it.question.contains(text) } as ArrayList<FAQQuestion>
            }

        }
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    inner class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        var questionsRecyclerView = itemView.faqQuestionsRecyclerView
        var faqSectionHeading = itemView.faqHeading
    }
}
```

Comment: please put your code.

Comment: What do you want to achieve here? `faqSectionsCopy.map {
                faqSectionsCopy[0].faqQuestions = it.faqQuestions.filter { it.question.contains(text) } as ArrayList<FAQQuestion>
            }`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass data by value in *Kotlin* or *Java*. Instead you should ensure to work on a copy when you retrieve the data:

```
fun withList(listOfLists: List<List<Any>>) {
    ...
    val list = listOfLists[0].toMutableList()
    ...
}
```

The [`toMutableList`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/to-mutable-list.html) extension function will then create a mutable copy of the list and therefore the original will not change. As both levels of the parameter are of type `List`, the values are immutable themself.

Comment: Kindly check the updated code, toMutableList is not working in my case for some reason

Answer (score 0):

Actually every data pass in Java/Kotlin is by value. Except that in this situation you're passing a reference by value but not the list itself.

To pass a copy of list, you can

- passed using `yourList.toList()` which will make a copy of the list and return an immutable list
- explicitly create new mutable `ArrayList(yourList)`